# Git strategies - master xcode project to different projects

Tags: git, xcode6

I wonder what the best Git strategy is if you are building different xcode projects off a master project. So they use the same core classes but maybe different assets and perhaps different views? Any major changes are always committed/merged back into the master project.

Do I create new xcode project then check out base classes, including the AppDelegate, create a branch or a clone?

Any other strategies? Part of where I want to head is creating a major part of this master project as a SDK so any ideas heading to that point are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), which will let you keep your common code in a git repository that can be incorporated into other repositories. The top-level repository won't track the individual files in the submodule, it will think of the entire submodule as one file and only track which commit `HEAD` points to in the submodule.

Edit (based on your comments): I suppose you already have a git repo containing both a "regular" project and the common code. I suggest the following steps:

1. Move common files to a separate directory (with whichever nested directory structure you want to have for your common files). Commit this.
2. Remove the files in that directory from the "regular" (henceforth called "top-level") git repo, without deleting them: `git rm --cached -r commonDirectory`
3. `cd commonDirectory` and `git init .`
4. Copy the `.gitignore` from the top-level repo if you have one, and add and commit all non-ignored files in `commonDirectory` to the new repo. You now have one git repository living inside another, but it's not a submodule yet.
5. `cd` into the top-level repository, run `git submodule add commonDirectory`, and commit that (together with the removal of all the files in `commonDirectory`).
6. Push your submodule repo as a new repo to whichever git server you're using.

Note that there are some subtleties related to cloning repositories that contain submodules.

Comment: Ok @Aasmund so if create submodules of core classes "like a library" from my master project, that why if I make changes to those core classes I can keep those separate repos up to date. Sounds like a nice strategy. Thanks, Accepted, chocolate muffin sent!

Comment: So I would need to separate the file structure those files into a folder and add and commit them, or can I create a submodule from a local git repo then add and commit. Then when I am in the other project I can use the git submodule add ["git_repo_url/new_sub_project"] to checkout it to that other project?